# Kendo UI trying to remove the last line from a line chart

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

https://i.stack.imgur.com/muXw9.png

Hey everyone, thanks first for helping me out!

I am trying to remove the to line on the chart 
But i can’t find any solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add to `valueAxis` definition that `max` that you want (in your case 10). Check documentation [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/dataviz/chart#configuration-valueAxis.max)

```
valueAxis: {
    max: 10,
    labels: {
        format: "{0}%"
    },
    line: {
        visible: false
    },
    axisCrossingValue: -10
},
```